# Why do electrons in battery not "go out" if there is no resistor in circuit?

Tags: resistors

This is what I always thought: Why do we always need resistors in our circuits? What if we use one battery and just a piece of cable without a resistor? Why do electrons in a battery not "go out" in these conditions, and why doesn't our circuit become complete?

Comment: Please clarify what you're asking, and do bother to include some schematics.

Answer (score 4):

The question is based on a couple of false premises.

1. Resistors are not always needed in every circuit. A simple example is a coin cell operating an LED. Or consider a lamp powered by household mains.

   In both cases you could consider the load (the LED or lamp) a type of resistor (i.e., it *resists* the flow of electrons), but it is doing useful work (producing light).

   Resistors, in general, are meant to *limit* current flow, so that other components are not damaged. However, they aren't required for every circuit.
2. The word ***circuit*** is defined as "a path or trip around something." If you don't connect your wire to the battery in such a way that you've created a loop, it isn't, by definition, a *circuit*. If you connect a wire to only one side of a battery (with or without a resistor), you haven't formed a complete circuit, and no current will flow. In order for electrons to "go out" of the battery, they must have a return path. This is because a battery is actually a sort of pump for charge (but not a charge pump, per @[Phil's comment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/79279/does-mah-measure-how-long-a-battery-would-last#comment155087_79283)). Electrons must flow from one terminal to the other in a complete circuit.

You may find it helpful to read about [basic electric circuits](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_1/3.html) at [AllAboutCircuits.com](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/).